# In a Polish space, a set is comeager if it is nonmeager in every open set?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category

In a Polish space, a set is comeager if it is nonmeager in every open set?

I read this from a proof of a paper. I'm quite new for the meager set so I didn't grasp it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No (assuming the Axiom of Choice).  For example, in $\mathbb R$ a Vitali set is nonmeager in every open set, but is not comeager.

EDIT:  On the other hand, if $A$ is nonmeager in every open set and has the property of Baire, there is an open set $U$ such that the symmetric difference $A \Delta U$ is meager.  Then $U$ must be dense, and $A$ is comeager.

Comment: I'm not sure that you need actual choice (with the caveat that you need some choice for the notion of "meager" to make reasonable sense, e.g. countable choice for sets of reals) to prove there is a partition of the reals into two non-meager sets. I'm not sure how one would go about proving this fact, though.